# C# .NET transferring variables from one form to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently working on a project in `.NET`, and I'm looking for a way to transfer the data of a simple string variable from Form1 to Form2. Does anybody know how to simply implement this? here's some code to clarify what I'm looking for:

Form1:

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
        // variables
        string username = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username = Textbox1.Text;
    }

  }
}
```

Form2:

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Form2: Form
    {
        string name = Form1.username;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click()
        {
            Label1.Text = name;

            // other option
            Label1.Text = Form1.username;
        }

    }
}
```

In the first form, I have a string variable called `username`, and I want to convert that to the string `name` in Form2. This is of course an oversimplified version, and **I know that this code doesn't work**, but does anyone have a simple fix for my problem here?

Help will be appreciated. Still a beginning coder :)

Comment: Modify the constructor: `public Form2(string userName)` and pass it that way.

Comment: "Anybody knows how to simply implement this?" A way? Sure. A *simple* way? Nope. This is one of those things that is more complicated then it has any right to be. It involves one form exposing a public property. And the other one creating and keeping a reference to that form. Or them both acessing some 3rd instance they share access too. | In WPF/XAML, this problem is forutnatley very solved.

Comment: @Christopher thx for the answers. I'm going to look into it. Like Christopher said, I'm starting to feel that they made this more complicated than it has to be. But thank you for the help.

Comment: @Christopher No need to keep references of anything. You can use Interfaces and DataBindings in WinForms. The difficult part is to explain how to use them. Not really simpler to explain when the platform is WPF. People here more often suggest *use the constructor*, *add a public property/method*, because it's simpler to understand if the OP doesn't know anything about Interfaces and DataBindings (if you knew these tools, you wouldn't ask these kind of questions).

Comment: @Jimi "You can use Interfaces and DataBindings in WinForms." A interface is uselss unless you keep a Reference to a instance of a class that implements it. And Databinding works via Events, wich are nothing *but* references. To code for once, but still..

Comment: @Christopher You don't need to *keep* anything to use an Interface, you already have  references that you can cast, without explicitly passing one anywhere public: the Form.Owner object, for example. The implementation details of DataBindings' internals are irrelevant, it's how you use them that counts. You don't need to know anything about the Form class (or any other) that generates the bindings, you just need to handle the high-level objects that provide the properties and methods that make the DataBindings work. + Nobody stops you from implementing in WinForms the same patterns used in WPF

Comment: @Jimi A interface can be used as variable type. Variables are there to store data. Whatever "solution" with a Interface you imagine, it involves storing a reference. | You are trying to that thinks that are clearly "storing a reference" are "not storing a reference".

Comment: @Christopher No need to store anything (not that it would imply anything relevant), just cats it when `(typeof([Interface]).IsAssignableFrom(type))`. If you apply the paradigm to an object that is already part of the default implementation (as the aforementioned Owner), you don't need to know anything about that object (except it implements the know Interface), nor you need to store a reference to it anywhere. You just cast it and use the properties/methods defined by the Interface alone.

Comment: @Jimi Congrats. You managed to take the bad solution you have to use in Windows Forms and made it *worse*. If you want to make a full example, you can write a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I know this probably isn't the best solution, but for me this was the best quick fix. I turned the variables that I needed to share into `public static` variables. And then made a new variable in the 2nd form that referenced the static variable. And I used that new variable in my second form.

Form1:

```
//variables
public static string username = "user1";
```

Form2:

```
//variables form 2:
string username-form2 = Form1.username;
```

This to avoid the usage of static variables in code. I know this could probably been coded better, but for now it holds up.